# Mysql Recursive Query - get all relationship

Tags: mysql, parent-child

I have a table as:

```
 id   | source_id
_________________
  1   | 1
  2   | 2
  3   | 2
  4   | 3
  5   | 4
  6   | 6
```

Result like:

```
 id   | sources
_________________
  1   | 1
  2   | 2
  3   | 2
  4   | 3,2
  5   | 4,3,2
  6   | 6
```

I prefered exclude all function OR procedures - need a pure ONE query with subqueries(if is necesary)

Comment: This is a famously difficult thing to do with relational databases.  It's often touted as the kind of problem the solve poorly, and graphing databases solve well.  Not that that really helps you solve your problem, but at least it identifies it as a Real Problem

Comment: Do you have a fixed maximum depth of relationship?

Comment: Dan, thank you for reply.Sorry, english is not my first language. It's hard to explain with my vocabulaire... My example is a smallest mechanism to do a final result than i want to do. Any idea?!

Comment: No, no depth - it will be in any case on preview(2 depth as default for example)

Comment: MySQL isnt good for Adjacency lists like this because it doesnt support window functions for Recursive Queries... i think you should convert to an nested set. read about it here http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/